# Json to datatable with proper column data get from json

Tags: vb.net

My JSON data looks as shown below. Sometimes it's changed the Field Name Position. How to store this data into a Datatable and must be in proper column. Suggest any solution for VB.Net

```
<string xmlns="http://tecogis.com/">[
    { 
        "REPORT NUMBER":"LG534248650",
        "REPORT CITY DATE":"June 22, 2022",
        "DESCRIPTION":"LABORATORY GROWN DIAMOND",
        "SHAPE AND CUT":"ROUND BRILLIANT",
        "CARAT WEIGHT":"1.07 Carat",
        "COLOR GRADE":"D",
        "CLARITY GRADE":"SI 2",
        "CUT GRADE":"VERY GOOD",
        "POLISH":"EXCELLENT",
        "SYMMETRY":"EXCELLENT",
        "Measurements":"6.41 - 6.44 x 4.10 mm",
        "Table Size":"57%",
        "Crown Height":"15.5% - 35.4°",
        "Pavilion Depth":"43.5% - 41.1°",
        "Girdle Thickness":"MEDIUM TO SLIGHTLY THICK (FACETED)",
        "Culet":"POINTED",
        "Total Depth":"63.9%",
        "FLUORESCENCE":"NONE",
        "COMMENTS":"As Grown - No indication of post-growth treatment\r\nThis Laboratory Grown Diamond was created by High Pressure High Temperature (HPHT) growth process\r\nType II\r\n",
        "Inscription(s)":"LABGROWN IGI LG534248650\u003cbr\u003e",
        "REPORT_SUF":"LEGAL",
        "PDF_FLAG":"Y",
        "REPORT1_PDF":"FDR534248650.pdf"
    }
]</string>
```

Comment: Use the Paste Special function in Visual Studio to create a class structure from your json, then you can use JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of YourClass)) methods to get it into something a little more manageable

Comment: Can You please provide code. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is the missing piece you need.  Note that it's from my own project so just adjust accordingly for your situation.

Before this, you just need to create a List of your custom type, populate it from your JSON (see Hursey's answer) and reference it instead of BlogList from my code.

This code will then transfer the data from your List into a DataTable which is the DataSource for the DataGridView.

```
'Declare a DataTable:
Private BlogTable As New DataTable

'Through code, modify a DataGridView instance on your form and clear things:
dgvBlogs.Columns.Clear()
dgvBlogs.DataSource = Nothing

'Set up our columns in the DataTable:
BlogTable.Columns.Add("blogname")
BlogTable.Columns.Add("username")
BlogTable.Columns.Add("password")
dgvBlogs.AutoGenerateColumns = True
dgvBlogs.DataSource = BlogTable

'Put data from JSON into the DataSource:
BlogTable.Rows.Clear()
For Each item As BlogRecord In BlogList
    Dim row As DataRow = BlogTable.NewRow()
    row("blogname") = item.BlogName
    row("username") = item.Username
    row("password") = item.Password
    BlogTable.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

So, conceptually, it's like this:

JSON -> List Of(Your Class) -> DataTable -> DataGridView.DataSource

You turn your JSON into a list of whatever custom item type you want to call it.  Then you populate a DataTable from that.  And you be sure that your DataGridView.DataSource property is set to your DataTable.

This works for me. The only thing to add is double-check the `AutoGenerateColumns` because for some reason in my code first I set it to True and then later to False.  I'm sure that was just me experimenting and I never cleaned it up.